# How to prevent base64 encoded PNG when saving large Matlab figure to SVG?

Tags: matlab, svg, base64, matlab-figure

I am trying to save a figure in matlab as `.svg`. The resulting `plotted_img.svg` contains the expected XML structure of the `.svg` and at one point contains an `<image  xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,[...]" />` tag with the image.

(I am sorry, that I cannot paste the necessary code parts here as they are currently part of a colleague's research. However, in order to reproduce, one has to plot lots of stuff into one figure with `hold on` and a `legend` with multiple entries.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the solution... while typing this question up. So, I thought I'd share my findings because I was unable to find a solution on StackOverfow.

In order to have matlab save a large figure  in a vectorized form one has to set the `'Renderer'` and `'RendererMode'` options manually, i.e.

```
set(gcf,'Renderer','painters')
set(gcf,'RendererMode','manual')
```

makes it work. See the Matlab Documentation here: **https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/figure-properties.html#property_Renderer**

I hope this helps other people that struggle with similar issues!